# WCF web service unreachable but control freezes on service call

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services

I have a strange situation happening in a little distributed application I am developing.

### The problem

Consider `N` servers where I want to deploy the same web service:

```
[ServiceContract()]
public interface IWS {
  int GetInt(int n);
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, 
 ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class MyWS : IWS {
  public MyWS() { /* ... */ }
  public int GetInt(int n) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Web service `MyWS` will be deployed on 8 stations. I do this locally using the same port but different application roots on IIS 7.0. So in one server I have `http://localhost:12000/Srv1/MySvc.svc`, while another one can be `http://localhost:12000/Srv4/MySvc.svc` and so on.

## Calls are routed

Consider that the method `int GetInt(int n)` is a method that can call another web-service for the same method. Actually what happens is that a call to `int GetInt(int n)` is routed until the destination is reached. Please do not bother with this detail, the important thing is just to understand that the call is routed, so calls are nested until one is executed into a server, after execution the reply is returned back until the original caller gets its reply.

When a `MyWS` web service wants to call another `MyWS` web service, it uses the following code:

```
public int GetInt(int n) {
  /* ... */
  if (/* a condition for routing the call */) {
    // Call another ws
    IWS svc = null;
    ServiceEndpoint endpoint = new ServiceEndpoint(
      ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(IWS)),
      new BasicHttpBinding(),
      new EndpointAddress(/* addr of the other server */));
      ChannelFactory<IWS> factory = new ChannelFactory<IWS>(endpoint);
      factory.Open();
      svc = factory.CreateChannel();
      int res = svc.GetInt(n); // <======== HERE
      /* ... */
  } else {
    // Execute the method here!!!
    /* ... */
  }
  /* ... */
}
```

### The problem

What is the problem? That when I try to route a call for a particular `int n` from a certain station, that call does never return! It blocks!!! But if I try the call from the same station but different argument, OK!

Actually I tried with the debugger and was able to follow the call chain. The problem is when the call chain reaches one server before the last one, the debugger stops at the line where I put the `<======= HERE` mark! While that line succeeds for the previous calls, when reaching the server before last, the debugger cannot enter the call and waits there for an infinite time (in binding config I set for 12hours timeouts).

I understand that there is not much info about this problem.
I just would like to know if there s anyone who has some ideas about the problem.
Consider that I already tried to check whether it was a problem concerning the `Instance`, but I have the `Multiple` behavior so calls should not block and, btw, why do other calls do not block???

Comment: 12 hour timeout? Are humans carrying data across? Please put a value that meets the average time.

Comment: @Kangkan: It is just a way to ensure me the possibility to freely debug the thing, of course before releasing the application reasonable timeouts will be used...

Comment: But this high timeout is giving you the 'freeze'!

Comment: Yeah I understand... But if I lowered this I would simply get a TimeoutException with no info about the error... I already did it. The real reason behind the freezing is something different... if it freezes it is not "because of" the timeout.